# Add custom footer to Shopify?

Tags: html, css, shopify, shopify-template

For my school project, I have to replicate an already existing page online.
I chose a webportal that I've used before as a student (e.g. https://www.findroommate.dk ).

I'm trying to replicate the website in Shopify, but I'm having problems with adding a "long" footer as the one you can see on the website.

Which document in the backend do I have to edit?

Comment: added tags and minor formatting adjustments

Answer (score 0):

As you are using shopify shop builder , you need to change in under edit-code of current theme. You can change the file under sections/footer.liquid there can be some file included in footer.liquid , so change accordingly. And to be more precise please check in theme.liquid file that what footer file is included and than follow accordingly.
thanks in advance.